# Does radio studio upgrade increases happiness level?

Tags: fallout-shelter

In Fallout Shelter it says, that radio studio increases dwellers happiness level. Does upgrade of this room increases this effect?

Comment: The radio room is supposed to increase happiness, but it's such a negligible increase that you're wasting dwellers, space, and power. It's easy to maintain 90+ happiness without it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The radio room serves two purposes:

1. To entertain dwellers in your vault
2. To broadcast into the wasteland to attract more dwellers

As @camelCase stated already, high Charisma increases the happiness of dwellers in your vault, as part of #1 above. Upgrading the radio room serves to point #2, in that it increases the chance of attracting a dweller. Expanding (adding additional rooms) of the radio room and putting additional dwellers into the radio room serves to make the cooldown for the search for dwellers to take less time.

So if you're interested in only keeping existing dwellers happy, high Charisma is what you want. (Plus probably a 3-room expanded radio room, so you can have the maximum number of high Charisma dwellers broadcasting)

If you're interested in finding dwellers in the wasteland, you'd want to focus on upgrading and/or expanding the radio room (or both) faster, and in my experiences, Charisma doesn't seem to have any affect on dweller-finding.

Comment: In that case, is charisma over 10 help anyhow? Because when I assing dweller with 13=10(+3 from outfit) charisma, room still saying "10" when I hold dweller over it.

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest, but I've read on this site that anything over 10 is wasted, but again, I don't know for sure. I don't generally use clothing to bump up anything over 10 because I don't expect it to do much, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @TimS. Not sure about radio room in particular, but boosting stats past 10 definitely DOES have benefits in other rooms (at least when I was playing ~4 months ago). It's most visible when rushing rooms - failure chance decreases with primary stat and Luck, and if you have 6 dwellers with +5 clothes (either +5 primary, +5 luck or +3/2), then you can rush twice at 0% failure rate, or rush once with 5 such + a 0-stat nobody to boost their happiness in a room-rushing happiness pipeline.

Comment: @Ordous Thanks for the info, that's very good to know. I'll be sure to train max primary and luck then. In the past I've always just used Luck mostly for those venturing out into the wasteland.

Comment: @TimS. There was a question somewhere here about each stat... Luck also governs how much randoms caps you will get when finishing production. With maxed out luck you can get to maximum caps in the vault pretty quickly (order of ~10 hours of play)

Answer (score 2):

Based on my observations only, but it may answer the question somewhat:

Happiness appears to be related to the charisma of people in the radio studio.  I have noticed drops when I take high charisma people out of the studio.

Having more radio rooms means more dwellers can be assigned, and potentially higher happiness (based on total charisma).

According to this [Fallout Wikia](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Radio_studio) page, the only bonus for upgrading radio studios is:

> Increased chance to attract a Dweller